# Pandas - Skip final X rows during read

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes databases come with proprietary markings at the end (ie the last 5 rows are copywrite notices), and these need to be ignored or they mess with the dataset. Simply using `skiprows` in combination with `nrows` to hardcode certain line numbers is not viable because different database files could have variable lengths. Is there a way to have pandas skip the last X lines from a file when using the various `read` functions?

Clarification:
The most common notification you find at the bottom of a data file in my experience is of the form

```
Name
Copyright (c) _____ All rights reserved.
Confidentiality Notice
Owner
Owner company
```

where all of these are just text in the first column stuck after 1 or more blank lines after then end of the data (the blanks can be dealt with using `df.dropna(how='all' inplace=True)`).

Note: python minus notation, ie `skiprows=-7` does not work, and also open ended hardcoding ie `skiprows=[195:]` does not work either (since the interpreter does not know how much longer the file is until it has already been read).

Comment: how about `skipfooter`?

Comment: `skipfooter` is unreliable since it breaks if using the c based interpreter due to name clash.

Comment: How about the `comment` argument.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: It is not supported if you're importing your data with `engine='c'`. Use `engine='python'` instead.

Comment: Cludge solution: `df.dropna(subset=[column_name], inplace=True)` can be done after import, making sure that `column_name` is one that won't interfere elsewhere. This can be risky, though, since if you ever have a `NaN` in that column at a later point it will be dropped.

Comment: Using the python engine is slower which can be significant with larger projects. This would be a last resort option.

Comment: `comment` requires that there be a known character on the line to be skipped. This cannot be guaranteed when parsing externally sourced data, nor can it be guaranteed that you can edit the database to manually add the character (and this requires doing every time as will, which invites mistakes).

Comment: The only possible solution count the number of lines and then skip the rows.

Comment: Try the   'error_bad_lines =False"  flag... Since those last lines should not parse properly. --hence no commas, tabs...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all but last line of CSV file in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689694/read-all-but-last-line-of-csv-file-in-pandas)